# Распаковка многомерных списков Python в один список

Tags: python

Есть функция которая принимает массив. Нужно распаковать его.

```
def flat_list(array):
    # your code here
    return array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert flat_list([[[2]], [4, [5, 6, [6], 6, 6, 6], 7]]) == [2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
from pandas.core.common import flatten
# from matplotlib.cbook import flatten  # либо так

def flat_list(array):
    return list(flatten(array))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert flat_list([[[2]], [4, [5, 6, [6], 6, 6, 6], 7]]) == [2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Я бы ради этого не тащил пандас.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [87]: data = [[[2]], [4, [5, 6, [6], 6, 6, 6], 7]]

In [88]: def flatten(data):
    ...:     for item in data:
    ...:         if isinstance(item, list):
    ...:             yield from flatten(item)
    ...:         else:
    ...:             yield item
    ...:

In [89]: assert list(flatten(data)) == [2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Можно сделать более гибкий вариант проверки: `if isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, str)` со следующим импортом `from collections.abc import Iterable`

Comment: йеп, оставим это для автора